# Installing composer on OSX with MAMP

Tags: macos, composer-php

I'm trying to install composer on OSX with MAMP and have used [this guide](https://gist.github.com/kkirsche/5710272), but it doesn't seem to be working.

On the final step I get the following error:

```
mv: rename composer.phar to /usr/local/bin/composer: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong?  I'm using OSX 10.9.5 and MAMP 3.0.7.3 and PHP version 5.6.2.

Comment: Well the error message tells you what's wrong.  Have you checked that `composer.phar` file exists and that the `/usr/local/bin` directory also exists?

Comment: `composer.phar` exists.  However `/usr/local/bin` does not exist.  In fact `/usr/local` does not exist.

Comment: OK, so that is the problem.  Create that directory.

Comment: Ok did that, now when i try to run composer, it doesn't work:
`Bradleys-iMac:~ user$ sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`
`Bradleys-iMac:~ user$ composer
-bash: composer: command not found`

Comment: So that's a `$PATH` issue.  I really feel these questions are basic-user level, let alone developer level.  There is an expectation that developers are advanced users at the very least.

Comment: I'm not an OSX developer - I am a PHP developer which is why i'm asking this question.  I thought this site was for asking questions??  It seems that you do not know the answer either so would probably be best to not answer at all in future :)

Comment: I told you the answer.  It's the `$PATH`.

Comment: I've already added this to my bash profile, is that what you are referring to? `alias phpmamp='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/bin/php'`

Answer (score 6):

Download composer.phar and save it into your project folder: http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar

Then open your terminal and type:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Once the file is open, enter the following code

```
alias composer='php ~/composer.phar'
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.10/bin:$PATH
```

Please note that I am currently working with php7.0.10 version. Just customize the code above with the php version you're working with.

`ctrl+o` to save the file 
`ctrl+m` to confirm format 
`ctrl+x` to close the file

Now reload the profile

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Tipe `composer` in order to check if is working

```
   ______
  / ____/___  ____ ___  ____  ____  ________  _____
 / /   / __ \/ __ `__ \/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/ _ \/ ___/
/ /___/ /_/ / / / / / / /_/ / /_/ (__  )  __/ /
\____/\____/_/ /_/ /_/ .___/\____/____/\___/_/
                    /_/
Composer version 1.2.2
```

if the text above is shown, then you're ready to go!

Comment: default shell is now ZSH on macOS Catalina