# How to alias /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/composer as just 'composer'

Tags: php, composer-php, alias, mamp

I've somehow got myself in a situation where to run any terminal commands I have to prefix it with `php`. For example to run composer commands I have to run:

`php /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/composer`

The problem I'm having is that when I then try to install a new laravel project by running:

`php /Users/ian/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel new my-project`

I get the error:

`sh: composer: command not found`

What is the best way to resolve this so I don't get the above error and can just use `composer` again going forward?

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324042/installing-composer-on-osx-with-mamp

Answer (score 2):

The path to the composer is probably missing in the PATH variable (I am assuming you are using Linux).

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/composer
```

Comment: Ye, I'm using Linux. I've added the above to my .zshrc but if I run ```composer``` I now get ```zsh: permission denied: composer```

Comment: Using ```sudo``` I still get ```sudo: composer: command not found```

Comment: Are you using Linux or MacOS. I'm pretty sure MAMP is not available on Linux

Comment: sudo does not preserve environment by default. There are several ways how to bypass that. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83191/how-to-make-sudo-preserve-path